# Swift string comparison failure due to newlines

Tags: swift, string, nslocalizedstring

I am trying to compare two strings
 1. String read from a .strings file using the api, `String(contentsOf: localizableFilePath, encoding: .ascii).propertyListFromStringsFileFormat()`
 2. Strings to be written to the strings file

The string comparison fails when there are newlines in the strings, i,e

the string 1 has newLine character in them so its like 
`"something
something"`

and string 2 is like `"something \nsomething"`

and the comparison fails because of this.

Comment: just filter the new lines before comparing them

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing occurrences of newline characters with an empty string: For example:

```
let inputString = "Something \nSomething"
let test = "Something Something"

test == inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "") // true
```

[image]

Comment: What is your `let test` was a multiline string literal?

Comment: You could try reversing the comparison, or removing the newlines from both strings.